# How to make Onclick event in Jquery if my input HTML id is string + php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hi i've searched alot in Internet about accessing html tag using Jquery if the html tag's id or Class have string and php variable for Example:

```
<input type='button' value='Save' class='btn btn-warning clicked' id="id_<?php $value1["ID"] ?>" />
```

Normally if i havn't a php variable inside the HTML id or class would be in Jquery like that:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
$("#id").on('click', function () {
//some code

});

});
```

with any help i'll be Thankful.

Comment: You have to append whatever in  $value1["ID"]  to #id in jquery

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use : `$('#id_<?php $value1["ID"] ?>').click(...`

Comment: Are you having any loop from which you are fetching `$value1["ID"]` ?

Comment: @freedomn-m actually i've tryed that before but didnt work

Comment: @KetanSolanki yes

Comment: Why dont just put the event listener on class, after that put checking inside the event to confirm it was clicked with ID_xxx

Comment: @AKZhang i have table filled with data using a loop and this button was inside a loop so how would i know if the second button in 2 cell for example is pressed thats why i used id_<?php variable ?>

Comment: You mean that there is a cell with a button. you need to know which button was pressed right?

Comment: You should have made it clear it was in a loop and the js code was outside the loop (or even in a .js file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".clicked").click(function() {
    alert("Button #"+$(this).attr("id")+" was pressed!");
});
```

Try this.. you just need to use **this** to get to know which button was pressed

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by not encoding data into the id but instead adding a `data-` attribute:

```
<input type='button' class='idbutton' data-id='<?php $value1["ID"] ?>'>
```

and then

```
$(".idbutton").click(function() { 
    var id = $(this).data("id"); 
});
```

Comment: thx alot it works!, i've got another easier Solution using  $("this").attr("id") 
   but anyway have a nice day Sir.

Answer (score 0):

html :

```
<input type='button' value='Save' class='btn btn-warning clicked newClassName' data-id="id_<?php $value1["ID"] ?>" />
```

Jquery:

```
$(".newClassName").on("click",function(){
var id = $(this).attr("id");
//Here you get the id also and you can do the processing.

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

your input:

```
<input type='button' value='Save' class='btn btn-warning clicked' id="id_<?php echo $value1 ?>" />
```

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#id_<?php echo $value1 ?>").on('click', function () {
    //some code
        console.log('clicked');
    });
});
```

where `$value1` is your php variable

**EDITED**
Example: on php file `index.php` I've tested below code and it's working

```
<?php
$value1 = 35;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type='button' value='Save' class='btn btn-warning clicked' id="id_<?php echo $value1 ?>" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#id_<?php echo $value1 ?>").on('click', function () {
        //some code
        console.log('clocked');
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not working in this case the JS compiler will understand the whole content as normal String.